# Is it possible to destroy the Morphing Grid?

Tags: power-rangers

In Power Rangers there have been various occasions where Rangers lose their powers. A few that stick out is the Might Morphin' Rangers when their Zords are destroyed prior to the Ninja Quest episodes, the Turbo Rangers when the Power Chamber is destroyed when the Overdrive Rangers lose their powers.

In Mighty Morphin' it can be interpreted that the connection between the Power Coins and the Zords are the same. However one would expect the Grid to be destroyed after Zordon's death but it was not. Lastly in Operation Overdrive the Grid is depicted like the internal parts of a computer (which may be non-cannon compared it's physical depiction in Dino Thunder).

This leads me to the question: is it possible to completely destroy the Morphing Grid?

Comment: Considering how long that show has been going on and keeps changing. I'd say no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the Operation Overdrive team-up "Once A Ranger", the Morphing Grid
>   was damaged by the combined powers of Thrax, Flurious, Moltor,
>   Miratrix, Kamdor, Mig, and Benglo. The grid was shown to have massive
>   electric surges firing off inside. When the Sentinel Knight restored
>   the Veteran Rangers' powers, it was shown that the only part of the
>   grid that had been damaged was the section that connected to the
>   Overdrive Rangers. Andrew Hartford managed to reinforce the Grid to
>   prevent further damage, but it had to be repaired from the inside,
>   which Alpha 6 did.[(source)](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Morphing_Grid)

This means the Morphing Grid is distributive, but requires a lot of effort, and it depends on the franchise owner to end the Power Ranger series or keep it going.

There is no information on whether Operation Overdrive is not canon, so we can think it's canon too.

> Each team of Rangers has a specific link to the Morphing Grid[(source)](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Morphing_Grid).

Its only Dino thunder where it is cleared that the Morphing Grid has physical significance.

> In Season 2 of MMPR, it was mentioned by Lord Zedd that the Grid is
>   maintained by a balance between the major forces of Good and the major
>   forces of Evil, i.e. in that time period, Zordon and Lord Zedd.[(source)](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Morphing_Grid)

So that means it's like [Yin and Yang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang): the grid will remain nondestructive until there is balance between good and evil.

Comment: Lol, by the franchise owners